# Columns in the vertical recycler view are not centered

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Left and right, I have different distances between the column and the edge of the screen. But I would like to see them the same.

**Current state**

[image]

**Item.xml**

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    ...
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

**Layout.xml**

```
</LinearLayout>
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">
     ...
      <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
            app:spanCount="4"
            .../>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a root element with a *match_parent* width and setting the *center_horizontal* of the embedded view.

**Item.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        ...
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**As a result:**

[image]